# As of 2018 Sept 21st. When is the scheduled Casper Proof of Stake expected to arrive?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

Where can one find updates on Casper POS? I hear its been constantly delayed. When is it expected to arrive? And is there an alpha/beta state where one can test it out now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest information has come from a [Techchrunch panel](https://techcrunch.com/2018/07/06/the-future-of-ethereum-looks-bright/) that included Vitalik Buterin and Ethereum researcher Justin Drake (among others). This panel, which took place in July 2018, discussed the future of Ethereum, including Casper POS and sharding.

[From the panel](https://www.ccn.com/ethereum-sharding-slated-for-2020-ethereum-foundation-researcher-justin-drake/), Drake said, "**My expectation is that Casper will come first — possible next year, 2019**”.

Drake continued with “Then in sharding we’ve actually broken it down into two big phases. Phase one is actually the data layer, so coming to consensus as to what data is in the shards. Phase two is all about the state, giving meaning to that data and the notion of transaction.”

**Drake believes sharding phases one and two will come in 2020 and 2021, respectively**

Comment: What was the previous proposed deadlines that they missed? I don't keep up with it much but wanted to know as alot of articles keep stating that they kept delaying it.

Comment: It was believed that Casper would be out in 2018 (see the original purpose of the difficulty bomb built into EThereum), but has been pushed back occasionally due to the complexity of it.

Comment: When was the difficulty bomb suppose to occur? And now pushed back to when?

Comment: They pushed it back to ~December of this year, but will be pushing it back another 18 months, I believe.

Comment: What happens when the difficulty bomb happens?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://etherscan.io/chart/blocktime) chart. You will see that the last bomb began in May 17 and ended in Oct 17. The bomb slowly increases the block time, thus creating a chart like this.